# Not able to add custom style classes for img, ul and blockquote

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have configured ckeditor in Drupal 7. All the classes are showing in 'styles' dropdown for other elements except img, ul and blockquote which are under 'Object styles' do not show in styles dropdown. Can anyone please help with the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: how about changing text format to `Full HTML`.

Comment: Changing to Full html doesn't work either. I have updated the module to ckeditor version 7.x-1.17 and 'Object styles' only show when I select an image. For example. Select Image in ckeditor and apply 'ul' to it. Now it shows all the object styles for ul, blockquotes and image. It should only show style when i select ul or blockquotes. Looks like an issue on selection of elements in ckeditor.